# Bash: concatenation of the specified file n times so that the resulting file length in bytes does not exceed a predetermined number

Tags: bash, unix, concatenation

That is all what I could do. Please help.

```
COUNT=$(( $FILESIZE/$(stat -c %s $FILENAME) ))
for i in $(seq 1 $COUNT); do
    cat $FILENAME;
done >$RESULTFILE
```

If you know some useful resources for learning bash, pease give ma a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues. The first is that you are not incrementing a *total size* during each iteration to compare against your limit that will indicate when you are done. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -f "$1" ] || {  ## validate filename given
    printf "error: file not found., usage:  %s filename.\n" "${0/*\/}"
    exit 1
}

fsize=$(stat -c %s "$1")  ## single file size
total=0                   ## running total size
flimit=$((3 * fsize))     ## set to desired multiple (can take as argument)
resfile=/tmp/resfile      ## set to wanted filename
:> "$resfile"             ## truncate file to 0

while ((total < flimit)); do  ## loop while total < flimit
    cat "$1" >> "$resfile"
    total=$((total + fsize))
done
```

Look it over and let me know if you have questions.

**Simpler Alternative**

Unless you have some compelling reason to use the size of the file, you can simplify your script by just concatenating the number of copies you need. e.g.:

```
copies=3               ## number of copies to resfile
resfile=/tmp/resfile   ## set to wanted filename
:> "$resfile"          ## truncate file to 0

for ((i = 0; i < copies; i++)); do
    cat "$1" >> "$resfile"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is that your `cat` is just outputting to the terminal on each iteration. Do this instead to iteratively append output to your output file:

```
COUNT=$(( $FILESIZE/$(stat -c %s $FILENAME) ))
echo -n >$RESULTFILE
for i in $(seq 1 $COUNT); do
    cat $FILENAME >>$RESULTFILE
done
```

Comment: OP is writing to the outputfile after the done. That is better then in the while loop, the outputfile only has to be opened once.